Microsoft SpatialAnchorsAccount - operation 'write' disallowed
I just started with Azure, and when i try to create my first ressource with Microsoft Spatial Anchors the deployment fails.
I have this error : The operation 'write' on resource type 'spatialAnchorsAccounts' is disallowed. (Code: DisallowedResourceOperation)

Allow the operation can solve the problem but i don't know how.
Can someone help me pls ?
I tried to change my subcription but nothing happend.

Do you have necessary permissions to create it? @Wassim

How can i know if i have the permissions ?

Go to Access control under your resource group and click on check access. @Wassim

I'm a "User, group, or service principal" and i have Azure subscription 1. Do i need to change it ? And what are the permissions required to deploy this ressource ?
Also there is no Managed identity available

Ok. Can you check if any policies are added to disallow the creation of spatial anchors accounts under your subscription. @Wassim

I have this error under my subscription : Classic administrators will be deprecated on August 31, 2024. After August 31, 2024, all classic administrators risk losing access to the subscription. Delete Classic Admins who no longer need access or assign an Azure RBAC role for fine-grained access control. Learn more
Can this help ? https://imgur.com/a/6lNzBZc

Refer to this ticket:  Microsoft.SpatialAnchorsAccount - deployment fails due to operation ‘write’ is disallowed.

Azure Spatial Anchors is scheduled to be retired in November, and new instances are not being onboarded.

I can reproduce the same issue when creating the Microsoft Spatial Anchors.

As confirmed by the developers, the cause of the issue is that  Spatial Anchors is going to retire in November and isn't onboarding new accounts. The operation being disallowed is expected.

Ok I understand thank you, do you have an alternative to this problem ?
I'm doing this tutoriel on Hololens 2 : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/azure-spatial-anchors-tutorials/

@Wassim You can check the info in this link: Azure Spatial Anchors Retirement You can contact the email in the announcement to confirm the alternative service.
